# Creating Sites in MOSS 2007 Using Web Services

Tags: web-services, site-creation

Can you create a SharePoint site (assuming the Site Collection was already there) with the SharePoint Web Services?  I've been thumbing through the API reference on MSDN but didn't seem to get anywhere but a few allusions to it being doable.  Anyone been able to accomplish this? Got a snippet to share? This is mostly for SharePoint 2007 but likely the API would be the same in 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/3eac0294-ef11-439e-90cc-00f03cbb7fb6) indicates it has to be done with the Meeting web service.  It has a lot of good outgoing links to solutions.

The basic construct listed is: `CreateWorkspace([Site Title],[Site Template],[LCID],[TimeZone Information]);` where site template could be something like STS#0.